# Save to PDF after running Formulas

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, bloomberg

I have been sitting on this problem for a while now. I have seen similar problems already being solved but so far applying those solutions just returned other errors to me.

I have a spreadsheet connected to Bloomberg. I want to save the spreadsheet as pdf with different Company names/tickers inserted. But the code runs through too fast.

So what i get back is only several pdf documents saying #N/A Requesting Data...
about 50 times.

I have already seen people using

```
 Application.Wait
```

or doing some random calculations like

```
 For x=1 to x= 10^9
```

just to buy time, but it seems the computer is occupied with those commands and doesn't work on my formulas in this time.

In a similar thread i saw

```
 Application.ontime + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Other task"
```

but this only returned errors to me so far.

Here is my current code so you can get an idea what I am trying to do. In the current version it tells (N Times) that all makros are deactivated or that Print1() is not available in this worksheet. Also I can see it running through in the same high speed as without adding the  Application.OnTime.

```
Sub All_To_Pdf()
Dim i,N As Integer
N=100


For i = 1 To N

Range("I4") = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 3).Value

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Print1()" 

Next

End Sub
```

And a simple print function

```
Sub Print1()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "FOLDER" & Range("A3").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
End Sub
```

Update:

Now I changed my tactic and avoided the topic by copying the values in a different excel and from there saving it to pdf.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Have you tried using [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function).?

Comment: Bloomberg formulas dont get refreshed/calculate while vba code is running...you need to run this code for each time for each ticker with the help of a button...and also here you should refresh bloomberg formulas `RefreshAllStaticData` before setting timer. Edit: you can use bloomberg API for this. data retrieval is very fast and no need to depend on bllomberg formulas.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns could you please be a little more concrete? I am not very good with VBA so could you please be more specific :)

Comment: @Maddy
Are you saying it is technically not possibleI to get a refresh usign formulas like =BDP or =BDH?
I tried using RefreshAllStaticData but Excel didn't find it. What i did find was RefreshAll but this didnt change anything. 
And how would I go about using Bloomberg API? Do you mean embed everything in code and not anymore in the excel sheet itself?

Comment: @cvaz its not possible to refresh bloomberg formula while macro is running. I remember, last year I have faced the same issue. after that I started using `Bloomberg V3COM API wrapper for VBA` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bloomberg formulas **do not refresh while a macro is running**. if you want to refresh Bloomberg formulas then you need to stop the macro and give time to refresh.

To refresh Bloomberg formulas use below any method before `End Sub`

`Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"`

`Application.run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"`

`Application.run "RefreshAllStaticData"`

To retrieve data from Bloomberg by using VBA wrapper and Bloomberg API.please visit below blog. it has step by step explanation and also few examples.

**Bloomberg V3COM API wrapper for VBA** http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.in/2013/05/bloomberg-v3com-api-wrapper-for-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your sub to download Bloomberg data separately and then add Application.Ontime for next task.
I mean something like this:

```
Sub Bloomberg ()
% Call your sub to download
% Application.Ontime
End Sub
```